# How to pass the `string` values to angular filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to filter the objects by it's status value. and i have multiple instance. i would like to pass the filter values by each of the filter calls. but not working, i am getting error, error details:

[error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=)&p1=is)

my html :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="issue in issueLogs | issueStatus:'Inprogress':'Open')">{{issue.Status}}</li>
</ul>
```

my filter :

```
angular.module("tcpApp")
.filter("issueStatus", 
    function () {
        return function ( object, param1, param2 ) {
            console.log( "params", param1, param2 )
        }
});
```

what is wrong here? any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra `)` at `issueStatus:'Inprogress':'Open')"`.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/u06hd4b6/)**